# What username and password should be used when mapping a network drive

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-8

I have an old windows 7 machine connecting to local linux server and have mapped to the server. And just got a new windows 8 machine, which can access the linux server. What I am trying to do is to map a drive for the new one as well. But when I do this it asks for the username and password. Do you know where I can get these username and password? Refer to [this](https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/entries/72415-Manually-Mapping-a-Drive-for-XP-Vista-Windows7-Mac-Linux) page.

Comment: If a username and password are set, usually you are the one who set them. It isn't some generic user name and password, or else it would be pointless because everyone would know the credentials. Have you tried your username and password that you use to login to the machine that hosts the network drive?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the user name and password of an account that exists on the linux server. It's exactly like you did on Windows 7. If you don't know the credentials, then you'll have to ask the linux server admin to give them to you.